# WriteXML with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, xmlwriter

Good day all!  I created an SSIS package that runs a SQL query, stores the results in a variable, and then is exported into an XML file using a Script Task.  The C# code is pretty simple and only a few lines and uses WriteXML to move the data from the SSIS variable to the file.  However, when the XML file is generated, the declaration at the top is being populated with:

?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?

I need the file to be populated with:

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?

Below is all of the code I have added to the C# script and I cannot for the life of me figure out where or how to change the declaration in the XML file (hours on Google searching).  You can see that I've tried and removed the XMLWriterSettings portion as it did not resolve my issue.  Any thoughts guys?  Is this something simple that I am missing or does my code need to be written differently?  Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        DataTable dt;

        //XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings
        //{
        //    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        //};

        dt = (new DataSet("Detail")).Tables.Add("Table1");

        (new OleDbDataAdapter()).Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::Table1"].Value);

        dt.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\charris\Documents\TestFileOutput\Result.xml");
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: I quit trying to resolve this in the C# code that generates the XML file and instead added a separate piece of C# code that searches the xml file and does a REPLACE and just simply replaces the declaration at the top with the one I want it to display.  This may not be the most efficient route but this is a small data set that I am working with and the entire package runs in 1 second so this will work for me.  Thanks for reading guys!